# Is there a limit to the number of channel entries that ExpressionEngine can handle?

Tags: channel-entries, entries

We currently run a site that has over 120,000 channel entries across our main EE install + MSM sites. As we continue to grow and add more channels and entries, I'm wondering if there's a limit to the number of entries EE can store.

I'm interested to hear about overall limits (perhaps imposed by the database) along with any channel specific limits, if they exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for certain how it would pan out in the real world but the entry_id column in the database is an unsigned 10 digit INT so technically there is a limit there. But it's pretty big. You should be OK until your 10 billionth entry.

Comment: Yep, it's mostly about how efficient your server hardware is at handling query load.